# Replace break in C

Tags: c, do-while, break

I am writing a program that is for a computer game of mastermind. When I first wrote it the teacher didn't tell us we couldn't use break so I did. But are not allowed to use break. I am trying to find a way to replace the break but changing the logic is hard for me to understand. Here is my working original code:

```
    //If number of matches is not equal to length, print the hints and check for pica's
    if(matches != LENGTH) {
        //First, print as many fermi hints as matches
        for(int i = 0; i < matches; i++) {
            printf("fermi ");
        }
        //Then, second loop to check for pica hints
        for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            //We use the i index if not used before
            if(!usedNum[i]) {
                for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
                    //Check if the digit is the same for given indices if not used already on guess
                    if(!usedGuess[j] && num[i] == guess[j]) {
                        //If so, we have a match but on incorrect position
                        usedNum[i] = true;
                        usedGuess[j] = true;
                        used++;
                        printf("pica ");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //If no used numbers, we print "bagels"
        if(used == 0) {
            printf("bagels");
        }
        printf("\n"); //line break after hints
    }
    //Finally, we return the num of matches
    return matches;
}
```

And my attempt to change it into a do while loop.

```
 if(matches != LENGTH) {
        //First, print as many fermi hints as matches
        for(int i = 0; i < matches; i++) {
            printf("fermi ");
        }
        //Then, second loop to check for pica hints
        for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            //We use the i index if not used before
            if(!usedNum[i]) {
                do {
                    //Check if the digit is the same for given indices if not used already on guess
                        int j = 0;
                        //If so, we have a match but on incorrect position
                        usedNum[i] = true;
                        usedGuess[j] = true;
                        used++;
                        printf("pica ");                        
                    } while (usedGuess[j] || num[i] == guess[j]);
            } 
            }
        }
        //If no used numbers, we print "bagels"
        if(used == 0) {
            printf("bagels");
        }
        printf("\n"); //line break after hints
    }
    //Finally, we return the num of matches
    return matches;
}
```

Reading up on implantations. My original code can be stated as do this until. However the new code using a while loop is do this while this statement is true. So for the original code I had stop conditions for my new code I have to come up with continue conditions right? Would there be a better logic loop to use?

I saw another post mention sub functions but we never covered them in class so I don't think we are allowed to use them regardless I am still unsure how the implementation would occur.

Comment: It seems your `break;` can be replaced with `j = LENGTH;`. What is the exact restrictions?

Comment: Most of the requirements are irrelevant to this. like no global variable and only material up  this last lecture so basic stuff. but your suggestion worked don't know why I didn't think of it. Thank you so much been working at this all day lol

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can use instead of `break;`. Since restricting usage of `break;` doesn't seem reasonable and there may be some other restrictions, I cannot tell if each ways will be accepted.

Changing the value of `j` to exit the loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
    if(!usedGuess[j] && num[i] == guess[j]) {
        /* snipped */
        j  = LENGTH;
    }
}
```

Using another flag to exit from the loop:

```
bool found = false;
for(int j = 0; !found && j < LENGTH; j++) {
    if(!usedGuess[j] && num[i] == guess[j]) {
        /* snipped */
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Using `goto` (maybe discouraged by some people but this is a valid syntax):

```
for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
    if(!usedGuess[j] && num[i] == guess[j]) {
        /* snipped */
        goto after_the_loop;
    }
}
after_the_loop:;
```

Comment: Thanks, follow up what is the advantage of the break if it can be done with theses other methods? Or are these only option because of this unique situation.

Comment: `break;` can jump out from the loop immediately. First and second option here are available because there are no code to execute to cause visible effect after that. `goto` also can jump out of the loop immediately, but it may be harder to understand the intension.

Comment: `break` expresses the intention clearly and succinctly.  It is often much easier to use than options that rely on causing the loop's termination condition to be satisfied, and it is more robust against code changes than such techniques.  The `goto` approach has these properties too, though it may not be quite as clear as `break`, and `goto` has an undeservedly bad reputation.  `break` is better here, but there are occasionally cases where `goto` is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your while loop, you initialize j to 0 inside the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    if (!usedNum[i]) {
        int j=0, k=0;
        while (j < LENGTH && !k) {
           if(!usedGuess[j] && num[i] == guess[j]) {
                usedNum[i] = true;
                usedGuess[j] = true;
                used++;
                k++;
                printf("pica ");
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this should do.

Answer (score 0):

For a case like yours, I would give strong consideration to merging the inner conditional into the loop condition:

```
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < LENGTH && (usedGuess[j] || num[i] != guess[j]); j++) /* empty */ ;
                if (j < LENGTH) {
                    // we have a match, but on an incorrect position
                    usedNum[i] = true;
                    usedGuess[j] = true;
                    used++;
                    printf("pica ");
                }
```

The loop just searches for an index `j` that satisfies all the wanted conditions.  If it leaves `j` less than `LENGTH` when it terminates then you know that that final value of `j` is one that satisfies all the other conditions, too.